# Android application crashes on executing notification code

Tags: android, notifications

This works fine with the emulator, but when installed on a device, is causing the application to crash.

```
 String frndName=getSharedData("myOnlineFriendName");
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
 Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
  .setContentTitle("Trace Me! Notification")
  .setContentText(frndName+"'s New Location:")
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
  .setContentIntent(pIntent)
  .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
playSound("n");
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

How can I resolve this?

LogCat:-

```
03-26 05:29:33.387: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:33.837: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:34.147: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:34.467: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:34.807: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:35.067: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:35.227: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:35.417: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:35.537: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:35.657: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
03-26 05:29:42.127: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-26 05:29:42.157: E/MapActivity(1016): Couldn't get connection factory client
03-26 05:29:42.697: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
```

Comment: please share the logcat

Comment: Which version of android does the emulator have and which one is the phone working on? The addAction method was added in API level 16. Maybe your phone has a lower level API.

Comment: show us your errors..

Comment: Working fine with Emulator, & no error exist there , ..But on Real device,"Application is stopped working Unfortunately"

Comment: On emulator : API 17, 
Ive tested the code on Galaxy S2

Comment: check my ans --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/15630064/1168654

Comment: i think you have diffrent error then you have asked.. so remove this notification code & check in device.. it working or not??

Comment: your error is : http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=ro.sf.lcd_density+must+be+defined+as+a+build+property&oq=ro.sf.lcd_density+must+be+defined+as+a+build+property&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i8i5l2.848.848.0.1374.1.1.0.0.0.0.353.353.3-1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.iL2M8h55cHk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44342787,d.bmk&fp=3f44ff35554d700d&biw=1366&bih=667

Comment: Still not working :( 
I think the Error may be because of something else as you said.
Let me check,

Answer (score 1):

Your below code is available in `API LEVEL 11 or ABOVE`. Thats why it cresh in below API 11 level.

Insted of that you can use this way.. you have to add `android-support-v4.jar` in your `res/lib` folder and also do this : `your Project property ---> Build Path --> add jar.` and `your Project property ---> Build Path --> order & export --> select all`. after this clean & run below code.

```
String frndName = "myOnlineFriendName";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Trace Me! Notification")
                .setContentText(frndName + "'s New Location:")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // playSound("n");
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

you can check your code is working in my `Android 2.1 Device`

[image]

Above API 11 :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, But i've tested this on API 16 & above.. but still crashing !!!

Comment: you have try my code?? check my edited ans... its working fine. make sure you have add android-support-v4.jar in your project/res/lib folder.